# Combine Unity NetworkMatch with an UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I've used the simple matchmaking, but how do I put this through a menu system using an UI?

I'm looking for an example using [`NetworkMatch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.Match.NetworkMatch.html).
It's my first time using an online multi-user function.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: The best that I can recommend with that information is to download "Network Lobby" Asset and scratch: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/network-lobby-41836

Comment: Thanks but it's fine now I got another approach, simpler